# How can i print path to matrix path in java?

Tags: java, dynamic-programming

code is here

```
public class MatrixPath {
public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {
    int m[][], c[][];
    int set;

    Scanner scan = new Scanner(new File("hw9_1.text"));
    set = scantiness();
    m = new int[set][set];
    c = new int[set][set];
    for (int i = 0; i < set; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < set; j++) {
            m[i][j] = scan.nextInt();
        }
    }
    c[0][0] = m[0][0];
    System.out.println(set);
    for (int i = 0; i < set; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < set; j++) {
            System.out.print(m[i][j] + " ");
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
    System.out.println(path(m, set - 1, set - 1, c));
}
private static int path(int[][] m, int i, int j, int[][] c) {
    if (i == 0 && j == 0) {
        return c[0][0];
    }
    if (i == 0) {
        c[i][j] = (c[0][j - 1] != 0) ? (c[0][j - 1] + m[0][j]) : (path(m, 0, j - 1, c) + m[0][j]);
        return c[i][j];
    }
    if (j == 0) {
        c[i][j] = (c[i - 1][0] != 0) ? (c[i - 1][0] + m[i][0]) : (path(m, i - 1, 0, c) + m[i][0]);
        return c[i][j];
    }
    int A = (c[i - 1][j] != 0) ? (c[i - 1][j]) : (path(m, i - 1, j, c));
    int B = (c[i][j - 1] != 0) ? (c[i][j - 1]) : (path(m, i, j - 1, c));
    int C = (c[i - 1][j - 1] != 0) ? (c[i - 1][j - 1]) : (path(m, i - 1, j - 1, c));
    c[i][j] = Math.max(A, Math.max(B, C)) + m[i][j];
    System.out.print("(" + i + " " + j + ")");
    return c[i][j];
}
```

}

I used the translator.
Code that utilizes dynamic programming to find the matrix path at its maximum value.
I can get the maximum value by executing the current code.
Text documents leverage the following:
4
1 1 1 1
2 -3 1 -5
-1 2 3 1
1 1 4 1

I want to track the path of the matrix to get the maximum value.
like this ->
max : 13
path : 0 0 > 1 0 > 2 1 > 2 2 > 3 2 > 3 3

Do I need to add a new method?
Or is it possible with the existing code?

Comment: its 4 x 4 matrix

Comment: one element is redundant in your example if it is 4x4 matrix. Which one?

Comment: What is path in your problem, is it from [0,0] to [3,3] indices?